# Extracting a parameter from a URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to pass a parameter to a WordPress site using a URL - for instance:

`www.fioriapts.com/?ppc=1` will be the URL.

I am intending to write a function in the functions.php file but the mechanics of how to extract a parameter in WordPress is beyond me. How can it be done?

I am finding a lot of examples on how to add a parameter to a URL using the function `add_query_arg()` but have found nothing on how to extract a parameter.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

When passing parameters through the URL you're able to retrieve the values as GET parameters.

Use this:

```
$variable = $_GET['param_name'];

//Or as you have it
$ppc = $_GET['ppc'];
```

It is safer to check for the variable first though:

```
if (isset($_GET['ppc'])) {
  $ppc = $_GET['ppc'];
} else {
  //Handle the case where there is no parameter
}
```

Here's a bit of reading on GET/POST params you should look at: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

EDIT: I see this answer still gets a lot of traffic years after making it. *Please* read comments attached to this answer, especially input from @emc who details a WordPress function which accomplishes this goal securely.

Comment: Huge thanks - this is a duh moment for me - so it is done exactly as it is done in standard html/php - Wordpress has so many custom functions I thought it would be different...

Comment: Thanks - I am familiar with POST - but the problem in this case is that it is not coming from a post - what they are wanting to do is put url links on other sites using the ppc parameter to identify the site the link is on - and have content vary depending on the value of the ppc parameter in the url -  $_GET doesn't seem to work - since it isn't coming from a post I am thinking.  Is there any other way to get the parameter out of the URL?

Comment: Or is what they are asking impossible?

Comment: $_GET should work regardless of how the URL is constructed. what is the URL being loaded? If you call `debug()` on the $_GET array what is returned.

Comment: Does this conflict with WordPress's [**`get_query_var`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)?

Comment: Alternative to `$_GET` is `$_REQUEST`, but _please_ for the love of security use [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) if at all possible. Lazily parsing raw URL parameters is how injection attacks happen!

Comment: This method is the only way around the stupid bug/feature of `get_query_var` and static home pages: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25143

Comment: @emc `get_query_var` won't work for custom query variables check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#more-information

Answer (score 98):

Why not just use the WordPress `get_query_var()` function? [WordPress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/)

```
// Test if the query exists at the URL
if ( get_query_var('ppc') ) {

    // If so echo the value
    echo get_query_var('ppc');

}
```

Since get_query_var can only access query parameters available to WP_Query, in order to access a custom query var like 'ppc', you will also need to register this query variable within your plugin or `functions.php` by adding an action during initialization:

```
add_action('init','add_get_val');
function add_get_val() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('ppc'); 
}
```

Or by adding a hook to the query_vars filter:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "ppc";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Comment: This is the right way - Wordpress discourages accessing $_GET and $_POST

Comment: But how can `query_vars` run after `init` where the parameters then gets extracted from the URL?

Comment: One additional note: The filter has to be added in the functions.php file.

Comment: This method will break the home page if you anything other than the blog for the first page. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25143

Comment: @froger.me why is that? Simply because using their functions is more robust / less prone to errors or is there any deeper reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Noniq because these functions do a lot of sanitization, which can be overlooked easily. This is not necessarily the method to use in a 100% of the cases, but it is to be the default one. The WPCS PHP_CodeSniffer rules raise warnings when data is accessed directly, and the developper should explicitly add an ignore comment flag if direct access is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this function

```
/**
 * Gets the request parameter.
 *
 * @param      string  $key      The query parameter
 * @param      string  $default  The default value to return if not found
 *
 * @return     string  The request parameter.
 */

function get_request_parameter( $key, $default = '' ) {
    // If not request set
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST[ $key ] ) || empty( $_REQUEST[ $key ] ) ) {
        return $default;
    }

    // Set so process it
    return strip_tags( (string) wp_unslash( $_REQUEST[ $key ] ) );
}
```

Here is what is happening in the function

Here three things are happening.

- First we check if the request key is present or not. If not, then just return a default value.
- If it is set, then we first remove slashes by doing wp_unslash. Read here why it is better than stripslashes_deep.
- Then we sanitize the value by doing a simple strip_tags. If you expect rich text from parameter, then run it through wp_kses or similar functions.

All of this information plus more info on the thinking behind the function can be found on this link https://www.intechgrity.com/correct-way-get-url-parameter-values-wordpress/

Answer (score -2):

In the call back function, use the $request parameter

```
$parameters = $request->get_params();
echo $parameters['ppc'];
```