# How to get category name which was passed in url in one page to another page

Tags: wordpress

I have to pass category name from one page to another page. In first page i am passing the category name in url  like this

```
 <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/register/?category=<?php echo $category; ?>" class="reloadPage">
```

I need to get the category name in second page from the url.
can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting a parameter from a URL in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652605/extracting-a-parameter-from-a-url-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wordpress function [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

In your example, it would be:

```
$category = get_query_var('category');
if(!$category){
  //There was no category in the query string
}
```

If the variable you are trying to get is a custom one, you have to add it to the scoper of WP_Query using a filter, as suggested by the documentation, before calling get_query_vars.

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "category";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Alternatively, you can use the `$_GET` superglobal to access the value directly, but i strongly advise against it.

Comment: I tried with get_query_var, but still category is not fetching.

Comment: its working now... how to pass two variables in one url for example category name= "fashion" and category url="https://www.wordpress.com". How to pass this both category name and category url in the url

Comment: `?category=<?php echo $category; ?>&category_url=<?php echo $category_url; ?>`