# How to send link in email having unique number and track back whether user has clicked on it in contact form 7 in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, email-verification

I have a requirement of verifying user's email id without registration or signup.
When user will complete the CF7 form, on form submit he should receive a link with some unique number in mail. And after clicking on that link he should be redirected to result page.
Also the click should be tracked back and update some flag in database.

I know WordPress but this requirement is completely new for me.
Please give solution how I can achieve this in above mentioned or other manner. Email verification is on priority.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

1 solution is to create a page template & pass user Email via GET parameter & use that email to save in the database. You can write the code in page template for that.

Now to send link to the user, you can use contact form hook

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 

    // Generate unique id
    $unique_id = uniqid();

    //Get user email & send link using wp_email()
    //Link format - https://yourwebsite.com/your_page?email=$user_email&unique_id=$unique_id
    //your_page will be the page template you create

}; 
         
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```

Once the user click on the link then the code inside page template which you have written to save email in database will run & save the email on database. This logic i used once it works for me

Comment: Can you please explain in depth about create a page template & pass user Email via GET parameter & use that email to save in the database?

Comment: You told you know wordpress so you can create page template. use this link to know how to create template - https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-custom-page-template-in-wordpress/ ......... Now to get value from URL see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652605/extracting-a-parameter-from-a-url-in-wordpress...... Use that value & save in database. You need to try then we can guide we can't write whole code. cheers

Comment: You mean to put CF7 form in this page template? This form will be appearing on one website page section . From there it should work.

Comment: Noooo. You can keep contact form 7 wherever you want but in this template you need to code to get email & save in database......... Do you know how to code?